# Creating payment session for allowed payment method as "sepadirectdebit" is not working

Tags: java, adyen

I am using adyen java library ('com.adyen:adyen-java-api-library:20.0.0').
When I try to create session with **allowedPaymentMehods as sepadirectdebit** It is giving a error response

```
{"status":422,"errorCode":"14_0408","message":"There are no payment methods available for the given parameters.","errorType":"validation","pspReference":"......"}
```

**Code:**

```
PaymentsApi paymentsApi;
            paymentsApi = new PaymentsApi(client);

            CreateCheckoutSessionRequest checkoutSessionRequest = new CreateCheckoutSessionRequest();
            Amount pAmount = new Amount();
            pAmount.setCurrency(...);
            pAmount.setValue(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setAmount(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setMerchantAccount(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setReturnUrl(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setReference(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setCountryCode(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setShopperReference(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setShopperEmail(...);
            checkoutSessionRequest.storePaymentMethod(true);                        
checkoutSessionRequest.setStorePaymentMethodMode(CreateCheckoutSessionRequest.StorePaymentMethodModeEnum.ENABLED);            checkoutSessionRequest.setRecurringProcessingModel(CreateCheckoutSessionRequest.RecurringProcessingModelEnum.UNSCHEDULEDCARDONFILE);
            checkoutSessionRequest.setAllowedPaymentMethods(List.of("sepadirectdebit"));

            CreateCheckoutSessionResponse checkoutSessionResponse = paymentsApi.sessions(checkoutSessionRequest);
```

Anyone has idea on this? What could be the problem?

Note: I have tried "**card**" as allowed method and it is working.

Comment: are you using Spring or another framework? are you using Jackson for JSON processing?

Comment: @BeppeC, I am using Spring framework and Jackson

Answer (score 0):

The `sepadirectdebit` identifier is correct and it should indeed make the SEPA payment method available in the `Drop-in`.
It looks like the SEPA Payment method has not been [added](https://help.adyen.com/knowledge/payment-methods/manage-payment-methods/how-do-i-add-a-payment-method) in the Customer Area configuration.

A way to test this is to **not** set `setAllowedPaymentMethods()` and let the `Drop-in` show all available payment methods.

Comment: I am using test account so, I have verified in the customer area configuration of the test account. SEPA Direct Debit is there.

I have tested by not setting the allowed payment methods. Drop-in is showing only Credit Cards.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you able to call directly the Adyen API `getPaymentMethods` https://www.postman.com/adyendev/workspace/adyen-apis/request/25716737-52ad4290-9e79-4f6d-b041-037e847d5c3e?ctx=documentation to confirm you get all payment methods as configured in the CA? Also you are using the `drop-in` and not the Card `components`, right?

Comment: Yes I have confirmed it by calling the API /paymentMethods directy from postman. it is providing all payment methods including sepadirectdebit.
And yes, I am using dropin.
Thanks.

Comment: which version of the drop-in? this seems a bug or misconfiguration

Comment: also how your implementation compares to https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-java-spring-online-payments/tree/gcatanese-gitpod-help/checkout-example? You can run the sample app (with your api key) to confirm the dropin loads all payment methods

Comment: I am using Adyen Web v5.43.0

It seems a bug to me.
If I keep amount = 0 just to save a payment details for recurring payment then It is not showing SEPA Direct Debit option.
If I keep amount  > 0 then it is OK. I can see the SEPA Direct debit option in dropin.

Comment: I see, for SEPA the transaction must have a minimum value of 0.01 EUR. https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/sepa-direct-debit/web-drop-in